# How is the value of connection.project.dir being determined?

Tags: buildship

In org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs (in the .settings folder) how is the value of the key connection.project.dir determined and how can I control what project buildship writes there?

I looked at this https://discuss.gradle.org/t/documentation-of-org-eclipse-buildship-core-prefs/18697 and it says that there is no documentation on the pref file.

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @AndreiF not to this day

Comment: The problem for me is that when i have a multiple project dependencies (eclipse) similar to a "chain" or multiple projects depending on 1 project (that has other dependencies), that property is always changed and my projects won't build correctly